# How to obtain rotation matrix from covariance matrix

Tags: matrices, vectors, covariance

This is needed in any dimensions, but for now let's consider 2 dimensions. I have sampled a function $f(x,y)$ at points $(x_1,y_2),(x_2,y_2)...,(x_N,y_N)$ using some unknown ordering of sampling. I only have two interrelated vectors, $X$ and $Y$. The covariance matrix of these vectors is e.g.:
\begin{align}
C &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
  1.0 & -0.5 \\
  -0.5 & 1.0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
From this covariance matrix it is obvious that "amplitudes" or variances of these vectors are equal, but they are about $-\pi/4$ out of phase. I need a general method to calculate the rotation matrix that will bring these vectors into kind of diagonal form (relationship) so that their covariance matrix after rotation looks like this:
\begin{align}
C_r &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
  1.0 & 1.0 \\
  1.0 & 1.0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
I admit that in real practice the rotation will only be approximate, but I need a method that will work precisely on simulated cases. In practice I actually need to rotate a random sample position so that it resembles direction of the original covariance matrix.

Comment: You find the answer [here](http://www.visiondummy.com/2014/04/geometric-interpretation-covariance-matrix/) with graphical plots to aid intuition

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!